# automatic paste value from clipboard (web base php and javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, text, clipboard

i've browse and search the solution with my problem, but i (still) can't fix my problem from the resource and article that i've search before.

I've copy the (text) value into clipboard from (c# form apllication) that i've build before.
QUESTION : how can i paste the (text) value in clipboard to textbox in web-apps (i'm using php, html and javascript) ?

note : i've set focus to the textbox in web page but i can't still the way to paste value of the clipboard into the textbox.

thx anyway.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use JavaScript to programmatically take whatever is in the clipboard _on the client PC_ and put it in a particular field? Is it relevant which application the value in the clipboard was copied from? (What does this have to do with PHP?)

Comment: exactly, i'll use php to handle the value that had been paste from clipboard, because i work in web base application. Do yahu have any idea to paste the value from clipboard? i've set my c# program to copy the value that i want into clipboard. So i want that value automatically paste in taxtbox in webpage.

Comment: JavaScript isn't supposed to be able to access what's in the clipboard - most browsers don't support it because it is a security problem. You could change your C# program to connect to the webserver itself...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that is possible. You should past the text using your c# application.

Comment: can i past the text through the web page via c# ? note : i want to paste into textbox in webpage

Comment: Yes you can send a key press window message with "Ctrl + V" to the browser.

Comment: You need to use the windows api. This you help you http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx